# Proposition that holds for both finite and infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

Is it generally true that if a proposition $p(n)$ holds true for any integers set of finite length $n$, then it holds true for an infinite integers set?

Comment: How about the proposition "A set of order $n$ is finite."

Comment: How about "the set has a maximal element"?

Comment: Or : "the absolute value of an integer in the set is bounded"

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not true in general.**

For example, think about one of these propositions:

- "The set is finite"
- "The sat has a maximal element"

(This is just a community wiki answer made from the comments so the question stops appearing in unanswered list.)